# Django queryset update method removes objects from queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

This is not expected behaviour:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(sent=False)

items.count() # 3

items.update(sent=True)

items.count() # 0
```

How to update objects without loosing them in queryset?

Comment: That's the exact code you're using? You're not doing something like `items = items.update(sent=True)`?

Comment: @JensAstrup ye, man, this is exact code, 
`items.update(sent=True)` returns int: 3 - number rows affected I guess

Comment: I just ran something similar with my own code, and running `update()` didn't affect the queryset (as would expected). Not sure what's going on here...

Comment: Ah wait - @shadow is right - the query is updated each time you refer to it, since you updated all of the items to be `sent=True`, checking again will give 0.

Comment: I am not lying :) http://i.imgur.com/3hto6hZ.png

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you run `.count()` you are doing another query.

So this is the expected behaviour - before you do the update, there are 3 objects with `sent=False`, and afterwards, none.

If you want to keep your results, you'll need to hold them in a variable.

```
items_count = items.count()
```

If you are not dealing with too many items, a potential solution to this is to listify the queryset.

```
items = list(Item.objects.filter(send=False)
len(items)  # 3
Item.objects.filter(send=False).update(send=True)
len(items)  # 3
```

This does of course mean you no longer have access to queryset methods (which I why I had to use `len` instead of `.count()`. This does mean though that you can use the models even after the update (but you need to remember that you're dealing with outdated instances if you're doing it this way - `send` will still be set to `False`)

Remember that querysets are **not** a list of models. It is a representation of a query that you can iterate over to get the results.

Comment: "hold them in a variable" I thought I did it here `items = Item.objects.filter(sent=False)` :)

Comment: I've added more to the answer - take note of querysets not being a list of models.